# Output of thermal_zone0

Tags: python, sense-hat

I am looking to get the output of thermal_zone0 (CPU temp) to display on my Sense-Hat. I now know how to print the temp thanks to @Joan but when i try the code below  but i got 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/python/sense-hat-master/RSE.py", line 15, in <module>
    cputempf()
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/python/sense-hat-master/RSE.py", line 12, in cputempf
    StringToOutput= str(CPUTemp/1000.0 * 1.8 + 32)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'`

Here is the code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from sense_hat import SenseHat
from time import sleep

sh = SenseHat()

def cputempf():
    f = open("/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp")
    CPUTemp = f.read()
    f.close()
    sh.show_message("CPU %s F" %f /1000.0 * 1.8 + 32)

while True:
    cputempf()
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: Your going to need to elaborate on how you have the led display setup and how you currently control it As you must first finish the led display before you begin writing the code to retrieve the data you wish to feed it.

Comment: @MohammadAli It's been edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your sense hat only outputs strings but your cpu temperature is being provided to you as a float, the code below should convert your float to a string and it should print ok

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from sense_hat import SenseHat
from time import sleep

sh = SenseHat()
def cputempf():
    f = open("/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp")
    CPUTemp = f.read()
    f.close()
    ### line below will convert the temperature to a string
    ##note the devision is used to convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit 
    StringToOutput= str(int(CPUTemp)/1000.0 * 1.8 + 32)
    sh.show_message("CPU %s F" %stringToOutput)
while True:
    cputempf()
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: You're repeating one of the original mistakes of the question in using `f` instead of `CPUTemp` for the calculation. And it is not necessary to convert to string when using the format strings. It should just work fine with argument specifiers as posted in the question - the mistake is writing `%f /1000.0` instead of `%(f /1000.0)`.

Comment: @Ghanima I'm still getting the error with both of your solutions

Comment: @sir_ian does `sh.show_message("any text here");` work?

Comment: @MohammadAli Yes it does, the problem is performing the math not displaying it.

Comment: @sir_ian does changing `sh.show_message` to `print("CPU %s F" %stringToOutput);` and tell me if the output is correct and constantly updating.

Comment: Still getting the error with no other output.

Comment: Your going to need to share the error, like the line number but I've made some edits, please screenshot the error this time if possible, or directly copy paste it as the line number and what it says word for word is very valuable, in debugging

Comment: We have to assume that your `show_message` is not processing the format string. If `show_message ("Blabla")` is working try something like: `StringToOutput="CPU "+StringToOutput+" F"` and `show_message(StringToOutput)` after the `StringToOutput` line given in M. Ali's answer.

Comment: @Ghanima Both your comment and Mohammad's answer work.

Comment: Please mark an answer as correct to close the answer

Comment: To close the question your going to need to choose a correct answer and click the green checkmark to the left of it

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet will print the temperature.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

f = open("/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp")
t = f.read()
f.close()
print(int(t)/1000.0)
```

Comment: What does `/1000.0` do?

Comment: @sir_ian It divides by one thousand.

Answer (score 1):

There are two mistakes here:

- using `f` instead of `CPUTemp` for the calculation
- the argument specifiers are used before doing the calculation `%f /1000.0 * 1.8 + 32` instead of `%(f /1000.0 * 1.8 + 32)` that's the part that throws the error. Assuming that [`show_message()`](https://pythonhosted.org/sense-hat/api/) handles format strings like `print` does - which apparently is not true. So while this is working with `print` it does not with `show_message()`. My final suggestion is to format the string first and hand that over to `show_message()`.

This should do (and is using format strings like intended by the OP):

```
def cputempf():
    f = open("/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp")
    CPUTemp = f.read()
    f.close()
    StringToOutput = "CPU {0} F".format(int(CPUTemp) /1000.0 * 1.8 + 32)
    sh.show_message(StringToOutput)
```